# What is visualization of gradient flow of a functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, gradient-flows

I don't work on functional analysis but during my study, I faced gradient of a functional. I read its definition, but I can not understand why it is a useful tool? Why if a flow can be written as a gradient flow, we would be happy?!

I know the answer about the gradient of a function, but have no idea about the gradient of a functional!

Can anyone help me?
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function

Comment: Just read the first section of these notes, http://www.win.tue.nl/~mpeletie/Onderwijs/Pisa2011/PeletierLectureNotesPisa2011.pdf . This should answer your questions.